# SELECT from database where 2 items in row aren't a specific value

Tags: mysql

I've got a table which contains the following columns: ID, Condition 1, Condition 2.

I'd like to select all rows where condition 1 AND condition 2 is not a specific word. let's say the word is "no".

So, I want to select all rows where condition 1 and condition 2 are not "no" and all rows where there is a "no" but only in one of the conditions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get rows where both conditions are NOT 'no'

```
SELECT ID, Condition1, Condition2
FROM Conditions
WHERE Condition1 != 'no'
  AND Condition2 != 'no';
```

to get rows where either one condition or the other (but not both) is NOT 'no'

```
SELECT ID, Condition1, Condition2
FROM Conditions
WHERE Condition1 != 'no'
  XOR Condition2 != 'no';
```

To do both sets at the same time:

```
SELECT ID, Condition1, Condition2
FROM Conditions
WHERE Condition1 != 'no' OR Condition2 != 'no';
```

ETA extension of query returns the row with id=1 IF that row does NOT have 'no' in Condition1 or 2:

```
SELECT ID, Condition1, Condition2
FROM Conditions
WHERE Conditions.ID=1
  AND (Condition1 != 'no' AND Condition2 != 'no');
```

Comment: Update: While this query works awesomely, could you perhaps help with a statement where other conditions must be met first? Lets say I want to select the rows per ID and then apply the OR conditions. If I only add the ID as "AND where conditions.id = '1'", it doesn't work as I'd hoped and instead returns all results.

Comment: @deyssen: Generally speaking, what you're talking about is called Boolean Logic.  You can group your conditions with parentheses. I'll add an example to the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from yourtable 
where condition1 !='no' or condition2 !='no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition1 != 'no' XOR Condition2 != 'no'
```